# How to save Mediaquery Size in a separate file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, media-queries

I want to save every button and container size as mediaquery as follow in a separate dart file.

```
class FrameSize{
  var SliderHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6;
  var addToCartButtonHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 14;

}
```

So I can call them wherever I want and change at a one place. Is that possible??

Comment: i don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you need something like a singleton. Im used to implement [Get it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) to make this. Its simple, create an file (you can give it any name you want), Im used to call it appData, like this:

```
class AppData {
  var isAuthenticated = false;
  User user;[...] you can place whathever you want
}
```

A file called locator.dart (once again, name it whathever you want):

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => AppData());
 [...] you can place oher singletons too
}
```

In your main.dart place this:

```
setupLocator();
```

At the begining of you main page before you call runApp()...

And now, when you want to use the data, you just do this:

```
    class DocumentBloc extends BaseBloc (im a big fan of bloc "pattern") {
    var appData = locator.get<AppData>();
    
    //... photo = appData.user.photo;
    //... locator.get<AppData>().user.photo works too...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

1)Create class:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FrameSize {
  //init method is static so no object creation is required
  static void init({
    required context,
  }) {
    //instantiate variables here
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    _safeAreaHorizontal =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.left + _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
    _safeAreaVertical =
        _mediaQueryData.padding.top + _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
    sliderHeight = screenHeight / 6;
    addToCartButtonHeight = screenHeight / 14;
  }

  //declare variables here
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double screenWidth;
  static late double screenHeight;
  static late double _safeAreaHorizontal;
  static late double _safeAreaVertical;
  static late double sliderHeight;
  static late double addToCartButtonHeight;
}
```

2)Instantiate it in your home screen(Do not forget).

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 FrameSize.init(context);
 …
 }
}
```

3)Finally, use it to set your widgets' dimensions.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    MySlider(
      height: FrameSize.sliderHeight,
      ...
    ),
    AddToCartButton(
      height: FrameSize.addToCartButtonHeight,
      ...
    ),
  ],
 );
}
```

You can also refer to [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a).